# Pandas- Comparing two columns with different indexes and different length

Tags: python, pandas

I want to compare these two columns. When I used isin(), it operates with index, so even though four values are in common, it only returns one True.

[image]

How may I tackle this?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC use:

```
df['new'] = df['id'].isin(df['authorid'])
```

If not working checj if same types, if numeric or strings are same in both columns:

```
print (df.dtypes)
```

Then try e.g. convert to strings:

```
df['new'] = df['id'].astype(str).isin(df['authorid'].astype(str))
```

Comment: isin() does not work in my case. Because of the index differences. I want 4 Trues, because all 4 values are in common. With isin(), it only recognizes the first one.

Comment: @semchena31 - if not working `isin` then problem is different, not in index. How working `df['new'] = df['id'].astype(str).isin(df['authorid'].astype(str)) ?`